# 2-tile Image Array in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix called my_matrix with 5 rows and 5 columns made up with 1s and 0s.

```
my_matrix <- matrix(c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1),nrow=5)
my_matrix

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    1    1    0    0
[3,]    1    1    1    1    0
[4,]    0    1    1    0    1
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

I want to find the number of unique 2-tiles in the matrix where the leftmost two entries are 1 and the rightmost two entries are 0. I'm aware that these may overlap.

How would I go about calculating this in R?

Comment: In the example, there are no rows with that condition

Comment: Are you looking for counts where the first 2 column values are 1 and the last two column values as 0?

Comment: I think you worded it better yes, apologies. That's what I mean thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can construct logical vector with `rowSums`

```
n <- ncol(my_matrix)
(rowSums(my_matrix[, 1:2]) == 2) & (rowSums(my_matrix[, (n-1):n]) == 0)
```

---

Or another option is to do an `xor` (exclusive OR) and then get the `rowSums`

```
rowSums(xor(my_matrix[, 1:2], my_matrix[, (n-1):n])) == 2
```